# Opportunity Trigger - Populate 2 Fields on custom object Every time Opportunity.LastModifiedDate Updates

Tags: trigger, opportunity, opportunitycontactrole

2 Objects: OpportunityContactRole (OCR), Close_Plan_Contact_Role__c (CPCR)

Fields: OCR - OpportunityId & ContactId; CPCR - Contact__c and Opportunity__c

Description: Every time LastModifiedDate updates on Opportunity, check for Ids in OCR that are not in CPCR. Add them to CPCR if they're missing.

Can someone help me figure out why this trigger doesn't throw an error, yet it does not update my custom object??

```
trigger opportunityLastModifiedDate on Opportunity (before update) {

    // (1) Query to find all OCRs that aren't in CPCR
    List<OpportunityContactRole > ocr = new List<OpportunityContactRole >([SELECT OpportunityId 
                                                                             FROM OpportunityContactRole 
                                                                             WHERE OpportunityId not in (
                                                                                 SELECT opportunity__c 
                                                                                 FROM close_plan_contact_role__c
                                                                             )]
                                                                           );
    // List to hold CPCRs to be added                                                                       
    List<close_plan_contact_role__c> CPCR = new List<close_plan_contact_role__c>();

    //(2) Iterate through each Opportunity   
    for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {

        // (3) Verify that the LastModifiedDate field has changed
        if (opp.LastModifiedDate != Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).LastModifiedDate) {

            // iterate through OCRs to add to CPCR list
            for(OpportunityContactRole ocr2 : OCR){

                // iterate through CPCR, populate fields, add to CPCR list
                for(close_plan_contact_role__c cpcr2 : CPCR){

                    cpcr2.contact__c = ocr2.contactId;
                    cpcr2.opportunity__c = ocr2.opportunityId;
                    CPCR.add(cpcr2);

                }
            }
            insert CPCR;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: The problem lies in the way you are handling the CPCR list. You are iterating on an empty list (CPCR) and filling up the same list inside the for loop and inserting it. How is the CPCR related to opportunitycontactRole, is it a lookup on opportunitycontactRole?

Comment: why is it before update trigger?

Comment: CPCR is not related to OCR. We need to use OCR in a way that we can't, so I'm trying to find a way to constantly pull its data and insert them into CPCR.

Comment: @Oleksiy, I figured it would require an "after" event because I'm dealing with a system-level field, but changing the event timing doesn't work either.

Comment: by definition, if Opportunity is being updated, then last modified date has changed (even if only at microsecond level) - so why bother checking?

Comment: Another colossal brain fart on my part. I wasn't creating the record.